# How to remove \n\t in Cypress?

Tags: cucumber, cypress, bdd

I am using BDD with Cypress. The element I want to check is

[image]

So this element is on the PageObject:

```
allowPriceEmbeddedBarcodeAtPOS(){       
   return cy.get('im-data-table.hydrated').shadow().find('tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)') 
}
```

And on the Step Definition file I have:

```
And("Global Configuration is set true", () => {
    platformadmin.allowPriceEmbeddedBarcodeAtPOS().should('contains.text','{"AllowPriceEmbeddedBarcodeAtPOS": true}')
    })
```

But when I run cypress it founds the element with \n\t

[image]

Any ideas how can I remove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex with `\s` to remove all whitespace

```js
platformadmin.allowPriceEmbeddedBarcodeAtPOS()
  .then($el => $el.text().replace(/\s/g, ''))
  .should('eq','{"AllowPriceEmbeddedBarcodeAtPOS":true}')
```

Ref Cypress recipe [have-attr-assertion](https://glebbahmutov.com/cypress-examples/9.4.1/commands/assertions.html#have-attr-assertion)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
And('Global Configuration is set true', () => {
  platformadmin
    .allowPriceEmbeddedBarcodeAtPOS()
    .invoke('text')
    .then((text) => {
      expect(text.trim().replace(/[\n\t]/g, '')).to.eq(
        '{"AllowPriceEmbeddedBarcodeAtPOS": true}'
      )
    })
})
```